# UIPicker view and UITable view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uipickerview

I am facing on common error in both UIPickerview and UITableview, i.e.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x4d32080> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key CurrencyPicker.'
```

and

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x4b2c070> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'
```

Please help me why these are.

I think it is due to datasource and delegate connection of tableview and picker view to fileowner. but I have done every thing right.

Plz help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Also make sure all the IB-outlets are connected properly

Comment: @ Joetjah : Ya, all the IB-outlets are connected properly.

Comment: Right click the XIB file with the errors and choose to open as source. Can you find the occurrences of the both `CurrencyPicker` and `tableView` and post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key) post could help you

Answer (score 0):

@Aman: Here is code:

@ Aman:in setting.h

```
@interface Setting : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>{
    UIButton *button;

    NSMutableArray *CurrencyArray;
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *CurrencyPicker;
}
```

in setting.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CurrencyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [CurrencyArray addObject:@" Rs "];
    [CurrencyArray addObject:@" R$ "];
    [CurrencyArray addObject:@" $ "];
    [CurrencyArray addObject:@" ƒ "];
    [CurrencyArray addObject:@" ман "];

    button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

    [CurrencyPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [button setTitle:[CurrencyArray objectAtIndex:[CurrencyPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    [button setTitle:[CurrencyArray objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [CurrencyArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [CurrencyArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```